# AWS s3 configuration to avoid waiting time for multiple request

Tags: optimization, amazon-s3, request

I have static content uploaded on S3 bucket.
When I hit URL for the First time, the contents take while to load. It has a single html page with multiple CSS and JS.
So is there any kind on configuration needed at S3 level to optimize.
I am trying to figure out settings such as number of connections like we have in Apache.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some sample timings to your question, to determine whether it is slow and to isolate the cause. See: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Answer (score 0):

There are no configurations available for Amazon S3. It just works!

Some ideas for speeding your download:

- Create a bucket that is located closer to you/your users (less latency)
- Zip your files before uploading to Amazon S3 (faster download)
- Check the [Network console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) in your web browser to determine where the time is being taken